# For IIS7 what is the default behavior when output caching has no rules added for .aspx files

Tags: iis-7, cache

If there are no rules for output caching under IIS7, would global.aspx or default.aspx pages be cached, by default, or not cached?

I am trying to see if we need to explicitly turn off caching for two sites, one with windows integrated authentication enabled and the other with form-based authentication enabled.

My impression is that anything with integrated auth isn't cached, but I would like to get some verification.

Answer (score 1):

By default, only static content is cached

To take advantage of Output Caching, to cache (semi-)dynamic content, have a look at [this article at learn.iis.net](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/154/walkthrough-iis-output-caching/)

Comment: Thank you. A company is trying to blame caching on a login problem we are having, but since there are no rules on caching, I doubt the global.asax would be cached, especially since authentication is required for logging in, but, I couldn't find anything that states this explicitly.